# How do we create our own scalable storage buckets with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Instead of using Google Cloud or AWS Storage buckets; how do we create our own scalable storage bucket?

For example; if someone was to hit a photo 1 billion times a day. What would be the options here? Saying that the photo is user generated and not image/app generated.

If I have asked this in the wrong place, please redirect me.

Comment: At that point you're getting a billion hits per day, you're going to have very specific requirements that are unique to you and will require hiring a team of subject matter experts. Don't try to pre-plan for the unplannable.

Comment: @coderanger I had several apps that boomed into millions of hits per minute, was using GC at the time. Would rather know how to scale my storage than lose hype and customers. Otherwise using K8 would be pointless :-)

Comment: Kubernetes is a tool, it does not replace learning the underlying components and working out how to tune/customize them to better meet your needs. You will never find 100% plug-and-play systems for that level of scale, every infrastructure/product/team is a little different.

Comment: @coderanger not really. There are a few base things most public systems need. A place to store apps (BE/FE) that scales. A place to access stored data like photos, videos, etc. Away to host and scale the database. There are already plug and play Helm scripts for this. Just one lacking for scaling volume it seems; which sucks.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to GKE or AWS objects storage, you could consider using something like [MinIO](https://min.io/).

It's easy to set up, it could run in Kubernetes. All you need is some PersistentVolumeClaim, to write your data. Although you could use emptyDirs to evaluate the solution, with ephemeral storage.

A less obvious alternative would be something like [Ceph](http://ceph.com/). It's more complicated to setup, although it goes beyond objects storage. If you need to implement block storage as well, for your Kubernetes cluster, then Ceph could do this (Rados Block Devices), whilst offering with object storage (Rados Gateways).

Comment: Minio changed the license recently and the server pings Minio on each start - be be prepared to talk to the sales team. When you need a free Open-Source alternative use https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs